If $\sqrt{500}x + \sqrt{402} = 0$ and $\sqrt{360}y + \sqrt{200} = 0$, then how do $x$ and $y$ compare?

I) $\sqrt{500}x + \sqrt{402} = 0$
II) $\sqrt{360}y + \sqrt{200} = 0$.
Which of the following is the case?

$x>y$
$x<y$
$x \geq y$
$x \leq y$
$x=y$

or no relation can be established.

My attempt is-
I) (√500)x = -√402
Or, 500x² = 402
Or, x² ≈ 20²/22²
Or, x ≈ ± 20/22
II) (√360)y = -√200
Or, 360y² = 200
Or, y² ≈ 14²/19²
Or, y ≈ ± 14/19
Thus, no relation can be established between x and y.
P.S.- Sorry I am new to this site, I don't know how to use MathJax. The reason I am posting this question is because my answer doesn't match with the one in my book. In other forums where I have posted this question, everyone solved it as a linear equation, and when computing the square roots they didn't consider ± values of x and y. They got single values of x and y, and answered that y>x. Please kindly help.

You're supposed to show what you tried so far so we can try to help you!

Sorry I am new to this site. I have made the changes, I hope they will suffice.

Why do you conclude that no relation can be established between $x$ and $y$?  When squaring, you introduce phantom values for $x$ and $y$.  They can't be negative because the original equations wouldn't hold in that case.

Note that $\sqrt{500}$, $\sqrt{402}$, $\sqrt{360}$, and $\sqrt{200}$ are all positive numbers: $\sqrt{r}$, for non-negative real $r$, indicates the principal (ie, non-negative) square root. Therefore, the "$\pm$"s are incorrect; both $x=-\sqrt{402/500}$ and $y=-\sqrt{200/360}$ are negative. ... It's not clear to me why you're approximating the square roots. You can compare the values $-\sqrt{402/500}$ and $-\sqrt{200/360}$ directly. (Eg, $-p/q$ and $-r/s$, for positive $p$, $q$, $r$, $s$, are in the same order as $-ps$ and $-rq$.)

If you square an equation, and then take the square roots, you will often introduce extraneous solutions. For instance, if $x=3$, you can square this to get $x^3=9$, and then take the square root to get $x=\pm 3$. You have generated the extraneous solution $x=-3$.
This is what is happening to you. You know from the original equations that $x$ and $y$ are negative; so you can ignore the extraneous solutions with positive $x,y$.
Edited to add:
By universal agreement, the notation $\sqrt x$ means the non-negative square root of $x$. So $-\sqrt{402}/\sqrt{500}$ is negative.

Okay, but even if I don't square the LHS and RHS, if I write the linear equation as, x = -√402/√500, then x ≈ ± 20/22.4, similarly, y ≈ ± 14.14/19.

If I ask you what is the value of a, where a = √36, you will answer with a = ± 6. Then why isn't the same happening here?

@AakhiChatterjee Where did you learn that $\sqrt{36}=\pm 6 ;?\tag*{}$ False: $x^2=36\Longrightarrow x=\sqrt{36};\tag*{}$ true: $\sqrt x\ge0 \text{ and }(x^2=36\Longrightarrow x=\pm\sqrt{36}).\tag*{}$

@AakhiChatterjee: See my edit.

Okay, so if it is given that x² = 36, then x = ±6. But, if x = √36, then x = 6, NOT -6. Correct?

@AakhiChatterjee: That is correct.

Thank you SO much!

Squaring both side of the equations must be done carefully because in general it introduces additional wrong solutions.
In your case, you could argue that, since
$$
\begin{cases}
x &= - \sqrt{\frac{402}{500}}\\
y &= - \sqrt{\frac{200}{360}}
\end{cases}
$$
$x$ and $y$ are negative, so you can discard the positive solutions.
However, you don't need to square in this case.
Let's suppose $x>y$.
So
$$
x>y \implies - \sqrt{\frac{402}{500}} > - \sqrt{\frac{200}{360}} \implies \sqrt{\frac{402}{500}} < \sqrt{\frac{200}{360}}
$$
because multiplying by $-1$ both the sides of the inequality reverses it.
Then
$$
\sqrt{\frac{402}{500}} < \sqrt{\frac{200}{360}} \implies \sqrt{\frac{402}{500} \frac{360}{200}}< 1 \implies \sqrt{\frac{1809}{1250}}<1
$$
The last inequality is clearly false because $\frac{1809}{1250}>1$. So the true relation must be
$$
y>x
$$

By your arithmetic, $x/y =\sqrt{1809/1250}>1$...

You have not explained the crucial point: that if $x$ and $y$ are negative, then $x/y>1\iff x<y$.

Edited. I hope it is more clear.

You start with :
$\sqrt{500}x=-\sqrt{402}$
or, $500 x^2 = 402$
No, that is wrong.
What is the meaning of or in this context. The meaning is that previous row and following row are similar. We don't loose any information when we replace previous row with following row.
But this is false.
Option 1)
You can say :
$\sqrt{500}x=-\sqrt{402}$
implies that $500 x^2 = 402$
... ...
If you use this word implies, you will continue your reasoning, and you should not forget to check at the end. It is necessary that $500 x^2 = 402$ , but it is not enough ...
Option 2)
You can say :
$\sqrt{500}x=-\sqrt{402}$
or, ($500 x^2 = 402$) and $(x < 0)$
And now , you can continue ...
But,
Why do you raise to square, is it useful ?
$\sqrt{500}x=-\sqrt{402}$
Or $x =-\sqrt{\frac{402}{500}}$
implies that $x \approx -\sqrt{\frac{4}{5}}$
